# alternative to inline css transform for jsx

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There are many stackoverflow issues when trying to use transform as an inline style in jsx, but the solutions use jquery (which I don't yet know how to use), or aren't inline where I can access javascript Date().  I am trying to rotate an image depending on the time of day on a 24 hour clock.

I would love if transform just worked in inline css for jsx as follows.

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
var totalseconds = hour*3600+minute*60+second;
var totalsecondsoutofday = totalseconds/86400;
var totaldegrees = totalsecondsoutofday*360;

<img src={clockbordersun} className="clockborder" style={{transform:rotate(totaldegrees)}} alt="error" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that can be accomplished with CSS can be done with inline styles or jss. The syntax is indentical except jss is camelCase, while CSS properties use `-`. Your only problem is that you aren't string interpolating the value. This should do what you need.

```
const style = {
    transform: `rotate(${totaldegrees})`
}
```

Comment: the inline transform:translate css seems to override the transform:translate of the css sheet .clockborder, I'll have to center it another way, I'll respond with what I figure out in this reply & accept this answer

Comment: I moved the transform:translate of the css sheet .clockborder to the inline style={{transform:`translate(-50%, -50%)rotate(${totaldegrees}deg)`}}, in front of rotate and it worked! Thanks andrew

Comment: Always happy to help. Best of luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={clockbordersun} className="clockborder" style={{'transform':'rotate(totaldegrees')}} alt="error" />
```

Comment: totaldegrees can't be called then ('declared but never used') within single quotes. but thanks

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem but would have been great if all I needed was quotes.  I think I have to do something more convoluted

Comment: style={{transform:"rotate("+totaldegrees+"deg)"}} this is closer but Andrew may have the answer if I can implement it